# how to return UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, ios4

I made a datePicker using IB.On click of a button I m unhidding the picker.Now what I want is on selection of any row in picker I want to display the selected value on a label & at the a same moment dismiss the picker.
Is there any delegate menthod of picker using which I can dismiss the picker and get the selected value same as textFieldShouldReturn method.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from "Value Change" event of the datepicker. Use a method to get the value and dismiss the uidatePicker. Note, the event is fired everytime you change the value in the picker.

Refer this [tutorial](http://jsasitorn.com/2010/06/iphone-uidatepicker-tutorial/).

Comment: thax 4 u help.It helped me lot.

Comment: but one problem is when i select any row the picker is dismissed.i m not able to chenge other things in date picker.the single click dismisses the picker.

Comment: yes it happens for every selection. So u need to find a new way how users will select from the picker.